# select2 initialization via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-select2

I have a following example: jsfiddle.net/3h4gX/12/

The first select 'categories1' has been initialized via pure javascript. The other one 'categories2' initialized via html code. When I choose elements in the 'categories1' they remain in the dropdown list, when in the 'categories2' they disappear from the dropdown list.

I need to have the same behaviour in the 'categories1' select element(items should disappear from the dropdown list). How it could be achieved ?

Comment: show us code, not a link to a fiddle

Comment: @Adjit, I have created a jsfiddle example where you can find a code. What is the problem ?

Comment: SO would like users to post code alongside a link to a fiddle. One of the reasons they prevent you from posting a link to a fiddle without showing any code. This way if the jsfiddle website is not working or if someone doesn't have access to jsfiddle they will still be able to properly answer your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, this is a bug in select2 css, mentioned [here](https://github.com/todc/todc-select2/issues/9).
To fix this, you need edit select2.css line 368 as:

```
.select2-results .select2-selected {
  display: none;
}
```